# How can i run a local javascipt project with index.html on npm server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to run a particular SPA project in vanilla js  that has a script and index.html. I am trying to run the same in my local but it needs to be on npm server.

Comment: For my clarity, what are you referring to with the phrase "npm server"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a simple HTTP or express server, then render your static files pointing to the folder you have your html, css and other assets files (this folder can be called 'public'). This should serve your app on a specified port.

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(9000, () => console.log('Running on 9000'))

module.exports = app;
```

This should run your project on the port 9000 if static files are kept in the 'public' directory

Another option is to use a package like 'serve'.

Either of these should work unless I am getting your question wrongly.

Comment: thank you, I am trying to run an application in a locally running web server

Answer (score 0):

This might help

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server-spa

**http-server-spa**

A small but fast static file server running on node, with built in history-api-fallback. Useful for serving up single page applications with frontend routing. You can start the server using the command line..